# Tensorflow - Op Type not registered 'CudnnRNN'

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to tensorflow and trying to set it up.

When I try to train a model using CuDNNGRU it seems to load correctly and then gives an error :

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: **Op type not
>   registered 'CudnnRNN'**

I do see a Cudnn_rnn directory in tensorflow/contrib for what that is worth.

I have python 3.6 and VS2013.

I have tried the following, but still getting an error:

- Both Cuda 8/9
- uninstalling/reinstalling tensorflow/Theano/Keras/TensorFlow

Honestly the setup seems so convoluted and touchy, I may have screwed something up.

Am I missing a to-do?  Some way to manually fix? Thanks!

Sample code I am trying to replicate:

```
def get_model(embedding, sequence_length, dropout_rate, recurrent, dense_size):
input_layer = Input(shape=(sequence_length,))
embedding_layer = Embedding(embedding.shape[0], embedding.shape[1],
                            weights=[embedding], trainable=False)(input_layer)
x = Bidirectional(CuDNNGRU(recurrent, return_sequences=True))(embedding_layer)
x = Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)
x = Bidirectional(CuDNNGRU(recurrent, return_sequences=False))(x)
x = Dense(dense_size, activation="relu")(x)
```

Comment: Can you post the code that produced that error?

Comment: Just edited!  Sorry am new, didn't see comment

Comment: Nice, you should post that an an answer rather than a comment, I'm sure it will help someone in the future. Thanks for following up on it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by doing :

pip install tensorflow --ignore-installed --upgrade

and then

from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib print(device_lib.list_local_devices())